# PHP PDO MYSQL JOIN

Tags: php, mysql, join, pdo

I have a table called cms_page in which each page has an ID.  I want to pull all the information from this table and all the information from cms_page_part table where page_id is equal to the ID i send to the page...confusing i know but here is my attempt:

```
require '../../config.php';
$conn = new PDO(DB_DSN, DB_USER, DB_PASS);

$id = (int)$_GET['id'];
//$q = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM cms_page WHERE id=$id"); 
$q = $conn->query("SELECT cms_page.id, cms_page.title, cms_page.slug, cms_page_part.* FROM cms_page LEFT JOIN cms_page_part ON cms_page_part.page_id=cms_page.id WHERE cms_page.id = $id"); 

$project = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Any help figuring out how to join these would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

**How to JOIN the two tables:**

```
SELECT id, title, slug, cms_page_part.* FROM cms_page JOIN cms_page_part ON cms_page.id = cms_page_part.page_id WHERE cms_page.id=$id
```

**Example of what I said in my comments:**

```
// Connect to database
$conn = new PDO(DB_DSN, DB_USER, DB_PASS);

// Page ID
$id = (int) $_GET['id'];

// Fetch page
$pageStmt = $conn->query(sprintf('SELECT * FROM cms_page WHERE id=%d', $id));
if ($pageStmt->fetchColumn() != 0) {
    $page = $pageStmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    // Fetch parts
    $partsStmt = $conn->query(sprintf('SELECT * FROM cms_page_parts WHERE page_id=%d', $id));
    while ($part = $partsStmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        // ...
    }
    $partsStmt->closeCursor();
}
$pageStmt->closeCursor();
```

**Example (with prepared statements):**

```
// Connect to database
$conn = new PDO(DB_DSN, DB_USER, DB_PASS);

// Page ID
$id = (int) $_GET['id'];

// Fetch page
$pageStmt = $conn->query('SELECT * FROM cms_page WHERE id=:id');
if ($pageStmt->execute(array(':id' => $id))) {
    if ($pageStmt->fetchColumn() != 0) {
        $page = $pageStmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        // Fetch parts
        $partsStmt = $conn->query('SELECT * FROM cms_page_parts WHERE page_id=:id');
        if ($partsStmt->execute(array(':id' => $id))) {
            while ($part = $partsStmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                // ...
            }
            $partsStmt->closeCursor();
        }
    }
    $pageStmt->closeCursor();
}
```

Comment: the one i slashed out brings me the title nicely but the errors are supressed on my page and i dont know how to turn them back on :(

Comment: Just so I got this right, both tables has a field named page_id, correct? And the page ID you're testing this out on, has a row in both tables with the same page_id?

Comment: no sorry...in cms_page its "id" and in cms_page_part its "page_id"

Comment: I just updated my original post.  THis works :@)  But i have another issue.  in cms_page_part there are different "parts" with the same page id.  Do you know how i can access each one specifically?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If there are more than one, then instead of doing a JOIN I'd just do two query's. Do one select on the cms_page table, then after that if a record was found, do another query to get all the "parts" and loop through them and use them however you need. I actually have to get going for awhile, hopefully that helps!

Comment: Johan: $id is an integer. His question was related to SQL, not PDO.

Comment: Johan: I updated the answer with a PDO example. I also added a prepared statements as I feel you're getting PDO and prepared statements confused.

Answer (score 0):

```
$q = $conn->query("SELECT cms_page.id
                    , cms_page.title
                    , cms_page.slug
                    , cms_page_part.* 
                   FROM cms_page 
                   LEFT JOIN cms_page_part ON cms_page_part.page_id = cms_page.id 
                   WHERE cms_page.id = '$id'");
```

Comment: @Johan this is actually PDO, it's just not written properly. PDO has indeed a method called query. http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php